# How to open a video clip from command line using VLC Player?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

I need to use VLC Player to open video clip via command line call.

How can I do that?

ps.

Trying to put the file name as the manual guide shows takes me nowhere succeeded.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just typing `vlc` followed by the name of the video clip?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: the file appears to be bad.  try opening another file

Comment: The file is perfectly fine. I can open it by double clicking on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type

```
vlc /location/of/video/clip.mp4
```

in the terminal

E.g.

```
vlc "D:\MyClip.mp4"
```

Comment: It doesn't work and that's why I asked

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes I have. Please see the error http://i.stack.imgur.com/TLBUl.png

Comment: So this is a specific-file problem. I can do `vlc /location/of/video/clip.mp4` in my PC without problem. Maybe you should go to https://forum.videolan.org to get better response.

Comment: I have posted on VLC forum but no answer up to now https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=119808&p=405209#p405209

Comment: I have tried with another mp4 file and things work as you said. Thank yo! Get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

what I noticed was, just change your default player to vlc, then you should be fine using the cmd command "/location/of/video/clip.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Try
Start "VLC Instance 1" "[Location of vlc.exe file]\vlc.exe" "[Location of mp4 file]\file.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

According to the man, the correct command is :

vlc "file:///PATH/TO/FILE"

Answer (score -1):

None of the above solutions worked for me either.
But this method does work for me:

run % "vlc.exe """ Clipboard """"